# Ajax return result integer value getting 0

Tags: jquery, http-post

Here I'm calling to my controller and I pass one object type as a parameter. But when I received the results,the integer type ID always getting 0. But from my controller it return the correct ID.

```
function saveLessonBasicDetails() 
{

 var basicViewModel = new Object();

    basicViewModel.ID = $("#lessonId").val();

    basicViewModel.Name = $("#Name").val();

    basicViewModel.Description = $("#Description").val();

    basicViewModel.Topic = $("#Topic").val();

    basicViewModel.KeyWords = $("#KeyWords").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/CourseDesign/SaveLessonBasicInfo",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '{"vm":' + JSON.stringify(basicViewModel) + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: SaveBasicInfoSuccess,
        error: SaveBasicInfoFailed
    });
}

function SaveBasicInfoSuccess(result) {

    alert(result.ID);

    $("#lessonId").val(lessonId);

    alert("Success");
}

function SaveBasicInfoFailed(result) {

    alert("Fail");

}
```

Comment: Can you post the value of JSON.stringify(basicViewModel)?

Comment: Tip: use `camelCase` for functions. `PascalCase` functions represent constructors in JavaScript, by convention.